# How to compute the probability of $P(a|b,e)$ given $P(a|b), P(a|e)$ and $A$ independent of $B$?

Tags: probability, self-study, bayes

The following is given:
$$
\begin{align}
P(b) &= P(e) = 0.1\\
P(a|e) &= 0.2\\
P(a|b) &= 0.95\\
P(a|\neg b, \neg e) &= 0\\
B &{\perp\!\!\!\perp} E
\end{align}
$$

Is there any way to compute $P(a|b,e), P(a|\neg b, e)$, and $P(a|b, \neg e)$ from this?
I have tried using Bayes rule to compute these which gives me the following:
$$
\begin{align}
P(a|b,e) &= \frac{P(b|a)P(e|a)P(a)}{P(b)P(e)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{P(a|b)P(b)}{P(a)} \frac{P(a|e)P(e)}{P(a)} P(a)}{P(b)P(e)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{P(a|b)P(b)}{P(a)} P(a|e)P(e)}{P(b)P(e)}
\end{align}
$$
However, I don't know how to continue this since I don't know $P(a)$. Also, I can't use this method to calculate $P(a|\neg b, e)$ since I don't know $P(a|\neg b)$.

Is this even possible with the information I have? It's a question for a uni assignment, but the assignment does state that you can make assumptions **when necessary**. But since I'm not sure whether it's necessary right now this doesn't help me much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you lost $P(a)$ in the denominator in your derivation.

Comment: Looks like I did, edited.

Comment: Here's another problem: $P(b,e|a) \not = P(b|a) P(e|a)$. Independence ($b \perp \!\!\! \perp e$) does not imply conditional independence ($(b \perp \!\!\! \perp e) | a$). [Look here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/22480). Calculating $P(a)$ is not a problem, though, since you can use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Would the following be correct, ignoring the previous derivations: $P(a | b, e) = P(a | b)P(a | e) + P(a | b)P(\neg a | e) + P(\neg a | b)P(a | e) = 0.96$? If I imagine a Venn diagram this sort of makes sense.

Comment: For me it doesn't make sense, I can't think of probability laws that would lead to that formula.

Comment: **"Is this even possible with the information I have?"** You can check that by looking at the number of equations they give you. $P(a,b,e)$ has 8 unknown values. You're given 5 equations explicitly. The conditional independence between 2 variables ought to give you two more. Finally, the fact that the full distribution must normalise to 1 gives you another, leaving you with 8 equations and 8 unknowns. Assuming all your equations are independent, you ought to have enough information here to get the answer.